# plugin for different writers

Tags: plugins, login

Does anybody know a way for having different writers with seperate logins? I would like to host a bunch of coaches/trainers with each having their own page they can modify. The plugin I'm using now is WP Customer area, but all the coaches are able to access each others pages. S there another way? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the user role ? Is it author or editor or custom role?

Comment: Right now the roles are author, but I've tried every setting and have discovered no way to give them acces to just one page instead of eaxhothers pages

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood you correctly, you want each coach/trainer to be able to publish a page that any site visitor can read, but not to be able to edit each others pages.

If you just set each of these users to the Author role, then that should work.

Comment: Yes, but then the coaches are able to edit each others pages, which is a problem with 500 coaches.

Comment: Actually I've just tested and Authors can make their own Posts, but not Pages, and they can't edit each other's Posts.

Does WP Customer Area change the capabilities at all that you know of?  Or have you used a role management plugin or some custom code to change the capabilities?